# How to start selenium with firefox driver

Tags: firefox, selenium

I try to follow this link: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

In `SetUpTest`:

```
protected IWebDriver driver;
protected ISelenium selenium;
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium(
        "localhost", 
        4444,
        "*chrome",
        "http://localhost");
    selenium.Start();
    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

When this line `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` execute, I have this error:

```
Additional information: Cannot find a file named '***[Link to my project]\webdriver.xpi' or an embedded resource with the id 'WebDriver.FirefoxExt.zip'.
```

When I change it to `driver = new ChromeDriver();`, it opens `firefox`, but it cannot find element although element already render.

How to make selenium works with firefox?

Comment: Is your code/framework hosted on GitHub or somewhere I can see how you have set it up?

Comment: Similarly to your previous question: stop mixing Selenium RC & WebDriver. You should take a step back and read the documentation. The documentation out there explains in **great detail** what you should be doing to get Selenium to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you was using C#, this appears that you have added Nuget packages of both Selenium .NET binding and Firefox Driver

I was following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium#create-the-test-project. It asks to add all these packages

> After the project is created, you must add the Selenium and browser driver references used by the browser to execute the tests. Open the shortcut menu for the Unit Test project and choose Manage NuGet Packages. Add the following packages to your project:
>
> Selenium.WebDriver
>
> Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver
>
> Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver
>
> Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver
>
> Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform

This is **wrong**. If you are using Firefox driver, you only need `Selenium.WebDriver` (maybe `Selenium.Support` as well) and `Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver`. You don't need `Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform` which will add the wrong `WebDriver.dll` into your project and the test run will complain about missing `.json` and `.xpi` file.